# DUNIT X , pass large number of strings

Tags: delphi, dunit, dunitx

I need  to  pass a lot of string values to a test procedure, the string parameters are
transferred as a commatext stringlist, code goes like below

```
[test]
[testcase(test1,'xxxx,yyyy,zzz, ........')]
procedure Test_transmitmany strings(S1, S2, S3,  .... Sx  String);
```

if my stringlist gets more than 255 char's I get  the error  below

```
[dcc64 Error] Unit_TClass.test.pas(197): E2056 String literals may have at most 255 elements
```

What is an elegant method to pass many strings to a test case?
I'm also not happy with writing the large stringlist in the testcase definition, looks pretty ugly.

Comment: This is a good moment to learn the difference between a "String" and a "[literal](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Declared_Constants)", so one understands why **Strings** can size up to 2 GiB, but String **literals** can only have 1/4 KiB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the string up into multiple lines with no more than 255 characters on any one line. Then the compiler won't complain.

```
[testcase(test1,'xxxx,yyyy,zzz,'
  + ' ........')]
```